# Como trocar uma imagem dentro de uma div pelo javascript

Tags: javascript, html, img

Preciso alterar a imagem dentro da div se a largura da tela for menor ou igual a 991. Eu fiz o código abaixo, mas não está funcionando, preciso saber onde estou errando e como corrigir.

**html**

```
<div class="dImg">
   <img class="dImg2" src="assets/img/path.svg">
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(window).load(function teste() {
    var tamanho = window.innerWidth;
    if (tamanho <= 991) {
        $(".dImg2").remove();
        $(".dImg").append("<img src="
            assets / img / path991.svg ">");
    };
});
```

Também teste com esse js

```
$(window).load(function teste() {
    var tamanho = window.innerWidth;

    if (tamanho <= 991) {
        $('.dImg2')
             .attr("src")
             .replace("assets/img/path.svg","assets/img/path991.svg");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho conhecimento em JQuery mas acredito fortemente que você não está alterando nenhum valor, pelo menos não no segundo código. Isso porque o método `attr` retorna o valor do atributo e o `replace` retorna uma string. Sendo assim, você não está definindo nada ao elemento.

Utilizando apenas JS puro, tente trocar a propriedade `src` da imagem como no código abaixo:

```js
function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById("myimg").src = "https://ispeakcode.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png";
}
```

```html
<img id="myimg" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/br/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=e57f45c9cfaf"/><br>
<button onclick="changeImage();">Troca Imagem</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Menor ou igual a 991**

```js
function teste() {
    var tamanho = window.innerWidth;

   if (tamanho <= 991) {
       document.getElementById("myimg").src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvQfa.png";
    };
}

// Chamada da função
teste();
```

```html
  <div class="dImg">
     <img id="myimg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/akFTE.png"/><br>
  </div>
```

**Maior que 991**

```js
function teste() {
    var tamanho = window.innerWidth;

   if (tamanho > 991) {
       document.getElementById("myimg").src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvQfa.png";
    };
}

// Chamada da função
teste();
```

```html
  <div class="dImg">
     <img id="myimg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/akFTE.png"/><br>
  </div>
```